# Soap error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" while using .net service in php

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to use a .net soap webservice in php, I've tried everything but I keep getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Here's the code I've got right now:

```
$client = New SoapClient('http://url.com/DesktopModules/IWebCSharp/webservice.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => true));
$head = array();
$head['PortalID'] = 0;
$head['UserID'] = 1;
$head['Username'] = 'foo';
$head['Password'] = 'bar';
$head['Encrypted'] = 'false';
$head['WebPageCall'] = 'false';
$head['ModuleId'] = 523;
$header = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'IWebAuthendication', $head);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$client->GetUser(array('GetUser' => array('someuser', 'Username')));
```

When I run this and check the request sent ($client->__getLastRequest()) I get the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.DotNetNuke.com/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:IWebAuthendication><!-- ALL THE AUTHENTICATION STUFF //--></SOAP-ENV:IWebAuthendication></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetUser/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The relevant part there is of course this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetUser/></SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Why am I not getting the parameter through? What am I doing wrong? I've searched a LOT, both here on SO and Google, but every solution I've seen that has been working for others is not working for me. This webservice is part of a DotNetNuke system and I can make this work if I use CURL so I know the webservice can't be broken but I really want to use SoapClient() calls instead because it's a lot easier and a lot less code.

Here is the relevant code from the .net webservice:

```
public UserInfo GetUser(string Username) {
 UserInfo objResponse = new UserInfo();
 try {
  IWebAuthendication objIWebAuthendication = new IWebAuthendication(IWebCredentials);
  if (!(objIWebAuthendication.ValidAndAuthorized())) {
   objResponse.UserID = -1;
   objResponse.Username = "Not Authorized";
   return objResponse;
  }

  objResponse = IWebUser.GetUserInfo(IWebCredentials.PortalID, Username);

  //  Do not return the password for a administrator 
  if ((objResponse.IsSuperUser == false & objResponse.IsInRole("Administrators") ==    false)) {
   objResponse.Membership.Password = UserController.GetPassword(ref objResponse, "").ToString();
  }
  else {
   objResponse.Membership.Password = "Administrator password is supressed";
  }
 }
 catch (Exception ex) {
  objResponse.UserID = -1;
  objResponse.Username = ex.Message;
 }
 return objResponse;
}
```

And here's the relevant part of the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetUser">
 <soap:operation soapAction="http://webservices.DotNetNuke.com/GetUser" style="document"/>
 <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
  <soap:header message="tns:GetUserIWebAuthendicationHeader" part="IWebAuthendicationHeader" use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:input>
 <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal"/>
 </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

How can I make this work in PHP with SoapClient()?

Comment: This is a generic programming error that really has nothing to do with DotNetNuke. You'll need to determine the specific object not being set; either from compiler warnings, using a debugger or by commenting out lines.

Comment: I know this has everything todo with some specific object not being set and I'm pretty sure that it has somthing todo with how I'm posting to the webservice from PHP, I can't see how this could be some programming error in the .NET code that I would be able to catch in a debugger or by commenting out lines because I am successfull in using this webservice both in SoapUI and by using CURL in PHP. I just don't want to use CURL, I want to use SoapClient or somthing similar. But it looks like I'm stuck using CURL :|